# Which version of The Curse of Fenric is available on BBC iPlayer?

Tags: doctor-who

The BBC released [over 800 episodes of Doctor Who](https://www.doctorwho.tv/news-and-features/over-800-episodes-of-doctor-who-programming-will-be-coming-to-bbc-iplayer) on iPlayer in November 2023.

*The Curse of Fenric*, the third serial of the 26th season, has three versions:

- The original release
- A 1991 video edition with 6 minutes of extra footage
- A 2003 DVD version with 12 minutes of extra footage

Which version is available on BBC iPlayer?

From the episode's [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curse_of_Fenric):

> Two further versions of this story exist: the 1991 video release incorporated about six minutes of extra material into the original narrative, and the 2003 DVD included a 'Special Edition' edited into a single movie-length feature, with new special effects, re-editing of some scenes, and 12 minutes of unbroadcast footage.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to determine this quickly from the episode length?

Comment: I don't have a version of the original release to know how long that actually was in comparison, not any knowledge of where the footage was added as it's been 20+ years since I've last seen the serial

Comment: *"Running to nearly 104 minutes, this digitally remastered Special Edition includes almost 12 minutes of extra material, new CGI special effects, and a remixed soundtrack in Dolby Digital 5.1 surround sound. (2003)"* - https://whospecialfeatures.fandom.com/wiki/The_Curse_of_Fenric

Comment: FWIW, the iPlayer version of Kinda is the original one, not the special edition with CGI replacing the rather lame physical effects in the climax.  So if that's a general policy, I'd expect other episodes to be the originals too.

Comment: There is _also_ the new omnibus version for Tales of the Tardis.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [version on BBC iPlayer](https://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/episode/p00vbjry/doctor-who-19631996-season-26-the-curse-of-fenric-part-4) is 24(ish)* minutes x 4 episodes. Minus approximately 1.45 minutes per episode for opening and closing credits, that equates to around **92 minutes in total.**

Since we know that the Special Edition runs to 104 minutes, this version (12 minutes shorter) is presumably the original version.

> **The Curse of Fenric - Special Edition**
>
> ***Running to nearly 104 minutes**, this digitally remastered Special Edition includes almost 12 minutes of extra material, new CGI special effects, and a remixed soundtrack in Dolby Digital 5.1 surround sound.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Who Special Featuers - The Curse of Fenric](https://whospecialfeatures.fandom.com/wiki/The_Curse_of_Fenric)</sup></sub>

*<sub><sup>(Episode 1 = 24.25, Episode 2 = 24.09, Episode 2 = 24.12, Episode 4 = 24.18)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

The Whoniverse on BBC iPlayer has the original four episode version as broadcast in the normal seasons section, but also the upscaled version of special edition with the extra footage from the Season 26 Collection blu-rays, which is used for the Tales of the TARDIS episode for Curse of Fenric.